# How to use helpers in a client-side Jade template using Backbone.js?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, requirejs, pug, momentjs

I'd like to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) (more generally, any other function) as helper in a Jade template, **both** for the server and the client. On the server (Express.js 3.x), I'm adding it to `app.locals`, and it works fine:

#### Server-side

```
// Locals
app.locals.moment = require('moment');

// Routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index.jade')
});

app.listen(config.get('server').port);
```

So using the `moment` helper works fine when the template (`index.jade`) is rendered by the server and then served at `/` as plain HTML.

#### Client-side

On the client (RequireJS modules system) I'm using Backbone.js along with, again, Jade in order to render views. How can I use `moment` helper in `navbar.jade`?

```
define(
    ['jade', 'backbone', 'text!views/navbar.jade'],
    function (Jade, Backbone, navbarTemplate) {
        return Backbone.View.extend({

            initialize: function () {
                this.template = Jade.compile(navbarTemplate);
            },

            render: function () {
               this.$el.html(this.template(this.model));

               return this;
            }

        });
    }
);
```

**EDIT**: based on Peter Lyons suggestion, I've wrapped `compile` function. `moment` works but `foo` doesn't (`p= moment()` vs `p= foo()`, the latter gives me cannot call function of undefined):

```
define(['jade', 'lodash', 'moment'], function (Jade, _) {

    return {
        compile: function(str, options) {

            options.locals = _.extend({
                moment:  require('moment'),
                foo: function () { return 'bar'; }
            }, options.locals);

            return Jade.compile(str, options);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke the compiled template function in the browser, there's no out of the box `app.locals`, so you would have to code it.

```
//customJade.js module
define(function (require, exports) {
    var jade = require('jade');
    var moment = require('moment');
    exports.compile = function(jadeString) {
      //build the normal jade template function
      var jadeFn = jade.compile(jadeString);
      //build a wrapper function with same API
      var customFn = function(locals) {
        //in the wrapper, add your shared locals as needed
        locals.moment = locals.moment || moment;
        locals.appName = "Super Happy Fun App!";
        //return the result of the real jade template function,
        //but with combined locals
        return jadeFn(locals);
      };
      //return your wrapper function instead of the regular jade function
      return customFn;
    }
});
```

.

```
//your backbone view module
define(['customJade', 'jadeTemplateString'], function (customJade, jadeTemplateString) {
   //blah blah your View subclass...
   template: customJade.compile(jadeTemplateString),
   //...
});
```

Comment: While this could work (but note that there is no `require` in RequireJS), I need to pass `moment` to all my templates. I'd like to make `moment` a global Jade helper, available in every template as a "native" function (the same as I would do in the server). Is there a way to accomplish this for the client?

Comment: requireJS provides a `require` function as well as `exports` and `module` to support CommonJS style modules. If you missed that in the docs, have a re-read. Answer updated to explain how to write a wrapper function.

Comment: Good example, thanks! I'm quite confused about locals... can I use your example with `options.locals`? See my other question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428984/empty-locals-while-compiling-a-jade-template

Comment: I've managed to get `moment` to work, but `foo` doesn't: I've updated my question. Can you spot the error?

Comment: I'd have to look into how/if jade remembers the options.locals passed to compile for later when the function is rendered. Have you tried following my example more closely where I add properties to the `locals` object that is an argument to the template function as opposed to the `options.locals` argument to the compile function?