# How can I use the "locals" option in jade compile(), client-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, requirejs, pug

### What I'm trying to achieve

Server is a Node.js application. I'd like to **share code with the client as Jade template helpers (for functions) or globals (for objects/variables)**. New helpers and globals should be available in every client template. This question is NOT about adding helpers to Jade when jade is used server-side.

### The code

I wrote a RequireJS wrapper for Jade `compile()` function, passing the `locals` object (filled with properties to share) inside `options`:

```js
// ./wrappers/jade.js
define(['jade', 'moment', 'lodash'], function (Jade, moment, _) {
    return {
        compile: function (str, options) {
            options.locals = _.extend({
                moment: moment,                    // moment function
                bar: 'foo',                        // Custom bar variable
                foo: function () { return 'bar'; } // Custom foo function
            }, options.locals);

            return Jade.compile(str, options);
        }
    };
});
```

### Problems and oddities

When I try to use `moment` **it works fine**:

```
p!= moment().format() //- Works: <p>2013-07-10T13:57:12+02:00</p>
```

However, accessing the custom variable `bar` gives me **no errors but an empty `<p>`**:

```
p #{bar} //- No errors but: <p></p>
```

When I try to call the custom function `foo()` it **gives me an error** ("*undefined is not a function*"):

```
p= foo() //- Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So, how am I supposed to use the locals options in the (client) Jade `compile()` function, for sharing code between the server and the client?

### Updates

**Update 1**: as per @explunit comment, renaming the property `moment` into `localmoment` (inside `options.locals`), gives me an error *undefined is not a function* with the template `p= localmoment().format()`. I can't understand why...

**Update 2**: the solution proposed by @Isaac Suttell (expression function instead of anonymus one) doesn't work, I'm getting the same error with `p= foo()`.

Comment: If you replace this line: `'moment': moment,` with this one: `'localmoment': moment,`, can you call `localmoment().format(...`?

Comment: @explunit with `localmoment` instead of `moment` I get _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'format' of undefined_... what does this mean?

Comment: there is still a missing bracket and a superfluous semi-colon

Comment: you say you get an empty `<p>` when you access `bar` but then in your snippet you show `#{foo}`, is that a typo as well ? Also, Is this your actual code ? I just want to know for sure you are not returning anything else then a hard coded static string from the foo function.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer yes, another typo (fixed now), thanks. I'm return a plain string from the `foo` function, template is `p= foo()`, getting _undefined is not a function_...

Comment: Can you be sure that you are not including moment.js on your client side. Try to compile the page without passing moment in locals. Based on your response to explunit's comment, I am getting a feeling that nothing is getting passed as locals, but moment executes because you are including it somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `moment().format()` only works because `moment` is a global variable, so it's not being passed in at all into your template.

The only way i know to get a function in to the template is trough the model it self.
There might be better ways but i got this to work.

```
define(['jade', 'moment', 'lodash'], function (Jade, moment, _) {
    return {
        compile: function (str, options) {
              var compileFunction = Jade.compile(str, options);
              return function(){
                  // augment the model with the functions/vars you need
                  arguments[0] = _.extend(arguments[0] || {}, {
                    foo: function() { return "bar"; },
                    bar: "foo"
                  });
                  return compileFunction.apply(null, arguments)
              }
        }
    };
});
```

Then if you define your template like this

```
p #{bar}
p= foo()
```

Everything should work nicely.

Comment: The brackets issue is a typo (the running code is correct), fixed, thanks.

Comment: your code is still not correct, you still have superfluous comma and now you have superfluous semi-colon as well and a missing bracket

Comment: Now the code is a copy and paste of my running code, but this is not the point: it doesn't work anyways.

Comment: you still have two missing semi-colons, sorry to nag about it !

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit The OP has already added them within the grace period of his previous edit

Comment: @gremo Any chance you can post a rar file somewhere with a dev setup so i can dig into this ?

Comment: Sure, here is the zip file (already includes dependencies), thank you: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26785590/nodejs-stack17568035.7z

Comment: I appreciate your solution, I'll give it a better look in a couple of hours. But it seems that you are using the model to pass globals/helpers, it may work but the question remains: how do we use locals? How locals are intended to be used?

Comment: I could be wrong but, I think that locals is an `express` feature, so if you set any locals in nodejs then off course they will not be available in the browser environment. You will have to implement the `locals` functionality in the browser environment, which is basically what i tried to do with my example.

Comment: @gremo, so did you find my solution useful ? Or do you think there is a betters solution ?

Comment: I had not time for looking at it, I'll do in the afternoon before the bounty ending. Thanks for your interest :)

Comment: Willem, I'm going to give the bounty, your solution works fine but I'm not satisfied with it. I guess this is not the right place to investigate further the `compile` function, I think I should open an issue on GitHub. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I hope you find a solution that fits your needs better, Thank your for approving the bounty, very cool !

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your function as expression function instead of an anonymous function:

```
define(['jade', 'moment'], function (Jade, moment) {
    return {
        compile: function (str, options) {
            var bar = function () { return 'bar'; }; // Function defined here instead
            options.locals = _.extend({
                'moment': moment,
                'foo': bar
            }, options.locals);

            return Jade.compile(str, options);
        };
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but still getting _Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function_...